# .What to use for Improving speech-to-text recognition accuracy using pocketsphinx?

Tags: pocketsphinx-android

I am totally new to using pocketsphinx, I have followed the integration of demo application as mentioned in

[Android offline voice recognition using PocketSphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999140/android-offline-voice-recognition-using-pocketsphinx/9079692#9079692)

It's working fine after integration of pocketsphinx as library in my application, but the output is not as accurate as desired. It's taking words even which are not being uttered from the provided dictonary.

I want to understand, how to improve accuracy of detecting words : I had initally used a .lm file; then instead of using that, I simply created a .jsgf text file and used it, but still there was no improvement in the accuracy, So after using .jsgf file do I need to compile it or something or simply copy pasting the .jsgf text file in the assests file is enough

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid in this link it is given building pocketsphinx-android. I have not done this. Just integrated it as library project

The Code:

```
public class SphinxSpeechRecognizerActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener {

    private static String TAG = SphinxSpeechRecognizerActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private SpeechRecognizer mRecognizer;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> mCaptions;

//    private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";
//    private static final String KEYPHRASE = "phone";
    private static final String COMMANDS = "command";
    private boolean mErrorFlag = false;
    private static boolean isRecognizerInProgress = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment);
        initViews();


    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }


    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "** onDestroy **");
        stopRecgonizer(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        stopRecgonizer(true);
    }

    private void initViews() {
        final ImageView img_close = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ttsClose);
        final ImageView img_voice_view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tts_voice_view);
        final ImageView img_info = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ttsInfo);

        img_close.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
        img_info.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
        img_voice_view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    }

    // Set press indicator
    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.ttsInfo:
                    break;

                case R.id.tts_voice_view:
                    if (!isRecognizerInProgress) {
                        isRecognizerInProgress = true;
                        setupRecognizerController();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Sphinx recognizer is already running");
                    }
                    break;

                case R.id.ttsClose:
                default:
                    // Call back event
                    onBackPressed();
                    break;
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.d(TAG, "** onBeginningOfSpeech **" + mErrorFlag);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.d(TAG, "** onEndOfSpeech **");
        mRecognizer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
        Log.d(TAG, "** onPartialResult **");

        if (hypothesis == null)
            return;
        mRecognizer.stop();
    }

    private void switchSearch(String languageModelSearch) {
        mRecognizer.stop();
        mRecognizer.startListening(languageModelSearch, 2000);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
        hideListeningBackground();
        stopRecgonizer(true);

        if(hypothesis != null){
            final String recognizedCommand = hypothesis.getHypstr();
            Log.d(TAG,"Recognized Text: = " + recognizedCommand + " Score: " + hypothesis.getBestScore());

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(!recognizedCommand.equals("")) {
                        if (recognizedCommand.equalsIgnoreCase(<given_command>)) {
                            Intent speech_converted_intent = new Intent(SphinxSpeechRecognizerActivity.this, Subclass.class);
                            startActivity(speech_converted_intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    } else {
                        showErrorMsg(Constants.MODE_SUCCESS);
                    }
                }
            });

        } else {
            showErrorMsg(Constants.MODE_DEFAULT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "** onError **");
        showErrorMsg(Constants.MODE_FAILED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeout() {
        Log.i(TAG, "** onTimeout **");
        mRecognizer.stop();
    }


    private void setupRecognizerController() {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
            @Override
            protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    Assets assets = new Assets(SphinxSpeechRecognizerActivity.this);
                    File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
                    setupRecognizer(assetDir);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return e;
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
                if(result == null){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Sphinx Recognizer: Start");
                    mRecognizer.startListening(COMMANDS, 3000);
                }
                displayListeningBackground();

            }
        }.execute();
    }

    private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {
        mRecognizer = defaultSetup()
                .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
                .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))
                .setKeywordThreshold(1e-10f)
                .setFloat("-beam", 1e-30f)
                .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)

                .getRecognizer();
        mRecognizer.addListener(this);

        File languageModel = new File(assetsDir, "command.gram");
        mRecognizer.addGrammarSearch(COMMANDS, languageModel);
 //       reset();
    }


    private void reset(){
        mRecognizer.stop();
   //     mRecognizer.startListening(COMMANDS);
    }

    private void stopRecgonizer(boolean flag){
        if(flag && mRecognizer != null){
            mRecognizer.cancel();
            mRecognizer.shutdown();
            isRecognizerInProgress = false;
        }
        hideListeningBackground();
    }

    String mShowText = "ERROR";
    private void showErrorMsg(final int error_type) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                switch (error_type) {
                    case Constants.MODE_FAILED:
                        // ...
                        break;
                    case Constants.MODE_SUCCESS:
                        //...
                        break;
                    case Constants.MODE_DEFAULT:
                    default:
                        //../
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

## My grammar file

```
#JSGF V1.0;

grammar commands;

public <commands> = (<label> | <mainMenu> | <subMenu> | <track> )+;

<mainMenu> = ( music
         | phone
         | navigation 
         | vehicle 
         | homepage
         | shortcut
         );

<label> =  ( back
                  | usb ( one | two )
                  | contact
                  | sms
                  | message
                  | dial
                  | ( homepage ( one | two | three ))
                  | ( shortcut ( one | two | three ))
                  );

<subMenu> = ( back
            | ( next | previous ) station
            | ( fm ( one | two ))
            | ( dr ( one | two ))
            | am
            | listen
            | play
            | ( next | previous )
            | search [ artists | playlists | songs | albums ]
            | call
            | received
            | missed
            | dial
            | address
            );

<track> = ( one
             | two
             | three
             | four
             | five
             | six
             | seven
             | eight
             | nine
             | ten
             | eleven
             | twelve
             | thirteen
             | fourteen
             | fifteen
             | sixteen
             | seventeen
             | eighteen
             | nineteen
             | twenty
             | (twenty ( one
                       | two
                       | three
                       | four
                       | five
                       | six
                       | seven
                       | eight
                       | nine
                       )
                )
             | thirty
             | (thirty ( one
                       | two
                       | three
                       | four
                       | five
                       | six
                       | seven
                       | eight
                       | nine
                       )
                )
             | forty
             | (forty ( one
                      | two
                      | three
                      | four
                      | five
                      | six
                      | seven
                      | eight
                      | nine
                      )
                )
             | fifty
             | (fifty ( one
                      | two
                      | three
                      | four
                      | five
                      | six
                      | seven
                      | eight
                      | nine
                      )
                )
             | sixty
             | (sixty ( one
                      | two
                      | three
                      | four
                      | five
                      | six
                      | seven
                      | eight
                      | nine
                      )
                )
             | seventy
             | (seventy ( one
                        | two
                        | three
                        | four
                        | five
                        | six
                        | seven
                        | eight
                        | nine
                        )
                )
             | eighty
             | (eighty   ( one
                         | two
                         | three
                         | four
                         | five
                         | six
                         | seven
                         | eight
                         | nine
                         )
                )
             | ninety
             | (ninety ( one
                       | two
                       | three
                       | four
                       | five
                       | six
                       | seven
                       | eight
                       | nine
                       )
               )
            );
```

My log shows:

```
I/cmusphinx: INFO: pocketsphinx.c(993): Writing raw audio log file: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.techmahindra.rngo/files/sync/000000000.raw
```

Comment: If you have two questions it is better to ask two separate questions and name them properly. For more details on how to ask on SO check http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: For getting help on accuracy you need to provide a dump of the audio created on the device. You also need to provide the code you are using.

Comment: I am really new to speech recognition and just followed pocketsphinx demo.                                                                                                                Dump of audio means some wave file or the grammar file ?

Comment: I suggest you to edit the question first according to recommendations

Comment: I used Imtool to create dictionary and again replaced the grammar file with .lm file. I am not able to understand how to improve the accuracy?

Comment: I suggest you to edit the title to match your question.

Comment: Thank you @NikolayShmyrev :)

Comment: Is the step "Building pocketsphinx-android" necessary as given in pocketsphinx demo tutorial : http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid , If I just need to use pocketsphinx as and speech-to-text engine and if yes then why ?

Comment: No, it is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy debugging is a complex process, there could be too many issues - noise in data, bad cpu speed causing delays in recording, bad estimation of channel.

In order to debug performance you first need to collect the data. Uncomment the call to `setRawLogDir` in demo and see in the logcat that raw data files are being stored on sdcard. Check those files to make sure audio is recorded correctly. Share the data together with the logs and your model to get help on accuracy. Make sure data is properly recorded, has no noise, has proper format, that you speak without accent.

In case you want to listen continuous and ignore words which are not of your interest, you need to use keyword spotting mode, not language model or grammar.

Comment: I have updated with the .jsgf grammar file I am using. Is there any problem with the grammar file I have created ?, also the log I am getting for raw data file is : I/cmusphinx: INFO: pocketsphinx.c(993): Writing raw audio log file: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.techmahindra.rngo/files/sync/000000000.raw

Comment: I used keyword spotting still the recognition accuracy hasn't changed much, any suggestions ?

Comment: You need to share raw files